# SQLite3 error when escaping string

Tags: sql, macos, sqlite

I'm creating an app which downloads a XML and inserts its values into a SQLite3 database. It was giving an error whenever there was a `'`, so I created this function to escape the strings:

```
+(NSString *)escapeString:(NSString *)string {
  NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [string length]); 
  NSMutableString *str =
    [NSMutableString stringWithString:string];  
  [str replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"\\\'" options:0 range:range];
  return str; 
}
```

The problem is that the database is now gimming the error `unrecognized token: "\"`. What am I doing wrong? BTW, I'm still using Tiger, can it be related to having an old version of SQLite? If yes, how do I solve that? Note that the app I'm creating must also work on Tiger and preferably, on Panther.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL does not escape with slash characters.  It uses single quotes `'` to escape within strings.

```
INSERT INTO xyz VALUES('5 O''clock');
```

[Reference](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q14)

So I assume (I don't know what language you're using) this line:

```
[str replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"\\\'" options:0 range:range];
```

should actually be:

```
[str replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"''" options:0 range:range];
```

You are going against the best practices by scrubbing the content yourself.  It's better to use sqlite's binding facilities.

Instead of doing the string manipulation yourself:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO xyz VALUES('"+ my_value +"');"
```

you'd use something like this:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO xyz VALUES(?1);"
```

Then use the bind calls to assign the contents of `?1`.